# How to get Dynamic URL with the help of Web.Config and PHP

Tags: iis, web-config

Suppose i have

3 php pages

- www.example.com/page1.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3
- www.example.com/page2.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3
- www.example.com/page3.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3

For good SEO . I need URL like

- www.example.com/page1/data1-data2-data3
- www.example.com/page2/data1-data2-data3
- www.example.com/page3/data1-data2-data3

i need all the variables for proper functioning of php pages. Some suggests me to use htaccess file but my website is on godaddy windows hosting so htaccess doesn't work .. 
.

Answer (score 0):

Go Daddy allows you to use URL rewrite module if you are on windows hosting plan. You can achieve the desired effect with URL routing.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module should give you all the information you need for setting up the appropriate rewrite rule.